# Data access abstraction with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, rdbms

Folks, we are developing a game server in Java. First there was JPA/Spring Data/Hibernate, then we've given up (thanks god) and we decided to use Hibernate directly. At this point I can say we are not going to change the technologies for data access, plain Hibernate and native queries if needed.

---

So my question is about the proper data abstraction at this point. Is there any sense to  go with the `Repository` pattern or for the god's sake give it up an abstract only `Session` and `Transaction` processing providing some kind of `Unit of Work` pattern?

- In case of the `Repository` there will be too many implementations with its own methods needed
- In case of `Unit of Work` we expose the hibernate `Session`, but provide the flexibility and encapsulate `Transaction` management at the same time

What are the pros and cons of each way to go? Any other strategies suggested? Could the `DAO` pattern be the solution or it is better to work with `Session` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [Ayende's advice](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)-
The `Session` **is** your database abstraction; you don't need an [abstraction on top of your abstraction](http://imgix.8tracks.com/i/000/235/601/c/yodawg-5618.jpg?fm=jpg&q=65&w=521&h=521).

Comment: that's the light's shine in the graveyard of design patterns . Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe how much *evil* Ayende did with that post. All those devs tying themselves to an ORM just because they don't understand a trivial pattern. Repository abstract PERSISTENCE as a WHOLE, not only a rdbms . I suppose no one would use NOSQl db and nobody needs apps that can use Redis or MongoDb as well as a rdbms.

Comment: @MikeSW I disagree. If you move to a nosql solution, THEN create your repositories. don't limit yourself in advance because of something that may or may not happen. your argument is a kind of premature optimization

Comment: No, I don't limit myself with anything. I don't really get it how can I limit myself when I'm NOT tied to anything. I'm starting with in-memory/fake repositories so that the app can function. After I'm satisfied with the business layer, I focus on the DAL and implement the real repository. The Repository is the CONTRACT between the DAL and other layers. The ORM is just a way to map tables to objects. Maybe this post will help you understand my point http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/04/07/Just-Stop-It!-The-Domain-Model-Is-Not-The-Persistence-Model.aspx